# how to make a framework in iOS that will automatically embedded in the project .?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have created a custom framework in Xcode 7.2 . when I drag that framework in any other project i have to manually embed it into the project by adding it from embedded binaries in Xcode. if I don't embed, it shows error like image not found .

but why Facebook or google frameworks are not required to be embedded into the project?

Can I also make my own framework that will get embedded automatically or that does'nt need to be embedded into other project?

Comment: You may want to use Pods (CocoaPods), since for example Google supports them since May 2015 for iOS Frameworks.

Comment: @ Larme - I don't want to use the pods , just want to make a framework that should not require to be embedded manually into the project